# Tomcat not extracting ROOT.war

Tags: tomcat6

Tomcat not extracting ROOT.war if i copy ROOT.war to `test.war`  then it is extracted as `test` and everything okay.Why can be this happens.I am using  tomcat 6.0.29 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting  work directory under tomcat  its working .

Comment: I've searched for hours, I've made a multiple instance Tomcat setup with different users but the only thing wasen't working was the ROOT.war deployement!